# Can I select a virtual table, its data and use it for other stuff with php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, sql-view

Is it possible to create a virtual table with JOIN, and then use that virtual table as a table to SELECT FROM when using phpmyadmin and php? If so, how do i go about by SELECTing from that table with php?

EDIT:

I tries using `view myview as <your select statement>` what said create

but i am getting an error: atal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool

Here is the code:

```
        $sqlEC = "create view myview as <SELECT hobio_id, hobio_pav2 FROM zmogaus_hobiai LEFT JOIN hobiai ON zmogaus_hobiai.hobio_id = hobiai.id WHERE zmogaus_hobiai.zmogaus_id =".$roww[0].">";
        $resultEC = $conn -> query($sqlEC);
        $var = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlEC);
        $rowEC = $resultEC -> fetch_assoc();
        $sqlH = "select id, hobio_pav from ".$sqlEC." where not exists (select hobio_id, hobio_pav2 from  zmogaus_hobiai where zmogaus_hobiai.hobio_id = hobiai.id and zmogaus_hobiai.hobio_pav2 = hobiai.hobio_pav);";
        $resultH = $conn -> query($sqlH);
        $rowH = $resultH -> fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: (1) You need to remove the `<>` around the select in the `create view` statement. (2) It would be simpler to run this DDL statement directly against your database, for example with phpmyadmin, if that's what you are using. (3) Then, you just `select ... from myview where ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a SQL view.

This is a virtual table that is defined by a SQL query, and that you can query just as you would query a real, persistent table. The database does not physically stores the view, only its definition. When the view is queried, the database executes the SQL statement that defines the view under the hood, and returns the actual data from the underlying table(s).

If you have a SQL `SELECT` query, you can create a view with the [`create view` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html):

```
create view myview as <your select statement>
```

You can then query the view with a regular `select` statement:

```
select * from myview
```